# How to get information from a JTable row when clicking on it with mouse?

Tags: java, jdbc, jtable, delete-row, mouselistener

I have an application which stores students, courses, what they are studying etc. The application is connected to a SQL database. I have no problem inserting or searching for stuff in the database through my application. But I still haven't figured out a way to delete rows in the tables through my application, in an easy way. I can, just like searching and inserting, use userinput in order to delete a row (example JTextFields) but I'd like an easier way. So I've figured out that if I add a popupmenu to my table, then I can rightclick a row and make it show "Delete row", as shown here

[image]

But now, I'd like to get the information in that row so I can send it to my frame, controller and later on database but I have no idea how. In this example I'd like to get "Lars" in a String and "12" in a int variable as you might imagine. So far I have created the code which does the thing in the picture. I've removed some code so it's easier to see what I'm getting at here. Any help is appreciated!

```
    table = new JTable(studentTableModel);
    popup = new JPopupMenu();

    JMenuItem removeItem = new JMenuItem("Delete student");
    popup.add(removeItem);

    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());

            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);

            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                popup.show(table, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    });

    removeItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

            if(studentTableListener != null) {
                studentTableListener.rowDeleted(row);
                studentTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
            }
        }
    });`
```

Comment: I know how this is done, but I'm not quite sure what your problem is since it looks like you're properly deleting the row already. You want to store the values after deleting the row, is that what you're asking?

Comment: Imagine that I have a String name and a int id somwhere in the code. I'd like to store, as show in the example, "Lars" in name and "12" in id when I press "Delete row". Which I will later pass on to the database so it can delete it.

Comment: Never, never call fireXxx mp event methods outside the context of the class that defines them, they are not your responsibility to call, it is the responsibility of the defining class to work with, you can easily screw things up doing this...

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to handle this.

#### ArrayList

You can declare a final ArrayList to keep track of the students. This allows you to keep track of individual students as they get deleted. The downside is that you can't undo a delete, so you'd have to clear the array and reset the model or it would not represent the database properly.

```
    final ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    
    removeItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

            if(studentTableListener != null) {
            
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setName(studentTableModel.getValueAt(...));
                //get the values from the row and fill a Student object
                list.add(student);
                
                studentTableListener.rowDeleted(row);
                studentTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
            }
        }
    });
```

Then, you could iterate through the list whenever you propagate to the database.

```
for(Student s : list) {
    //do call to delete s from database
}
```

And afterwards, clear the list.

```
list.clear();
```

#### Undo Events

A [tutorial](http://www.jroller.com/nweber/entry/undo_in_jtable) can be found here for how to implement an undoable JTable, which is more complex. This would allow you to roll back deletes and changes. I don't have the specific code related to this (it's significantly larger, but supports the JTable much better).

However, you'd basically create your own UndoAction for row deletes, and have it store the row being deleted.

Whenever you do a delete, you'd store a `RowDeleteUndo` event that stores an array of all the values you deleted. You can then override the `toString()` method or create a new method to get all the values out in a Student object.

Then, when you commit, you take the stack from the undo tree and iterate through it backwards (it's last-in-first-out by default) and commit in that order if you want to mirror the user's operations.

Comment: It's ok that I can not undo a delete. So the first method is legit. But, I'm not following you. I kind of understand the concept but I just "don't get it". I understand that the ArrayList stores the students, but when I create a student I need to put in the arguments for it, which is a String and an int. Also, the line after that, I'm not following you there at all. The three dots? The setName?

Comment: My setName method accepts just one String. Which makes that line impossible for me. And the getValueAt accepts two ints, row and column.

Comment: Well, I didn't know what you wanted to store. If it's just name and Pnr, then you just create a Student class that stores name and pnr. You just want something to store the values of what you're deleting. I don't know the exact specs of your table model, but you should be able to fetch the entire row of data when you delete using the column names you've created, one cell at a time, and then set those values into the storing object.

Comment: I have a class which does that and it's called Student and in that class I have getters and setters for the name and pnr. I think I've understood that part. The thing is, the getValueAt is confusing for me. My getValueAt accepts two ints as I said previously, and those are called row and column. In that method I use switch on the column to return student.getName and student.getPnr (cases). In other words, I can't write setName(studentTableModel.getValueAt(...) because the setName method accepts only a String and here I'm trying to send a object? Not sure if I'm making any sense now.

Comment: @Dinco OH. Cast it to String :P

Comment: @Dinco well, there is a way to get the data from the row. I don't have the application I built, but I implemented the second solution, so I know it's possible to pull the info.